# Vuetify: How to clear Autocomplete field using a button

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an autocomplete field that I want to be able to clear from a button. However, if something has been selected and/or there are `chips` in the field, they do not clear even if the the v-model has been set to null. Is there a clean way for this to be done?

```html
<v-autocomplete
    v-model="contract"
    item-value="id"
    item-text="name"
    :items="items"
    dense
    outlined
    clearable
    chips
    deletable-chips
    small-chips
    multiple
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component has a `reset()` method that clears the input along with the model.

Use a [template ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on the `v-autocomplete` to get a reference to it via [`this.$refs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs), and call its `reset()` method:

```html
<v-autocomplete ref="input">...</v-autocomplete>
<v-btn @click="clearInput">Reset</v-btn>
```

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    clearInput() {
      this.$refs.input.reset()
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QWGRZJK?editors=1010)